# How to redirect the output of Start-ThreadJob with -StreamingHost parameter to a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, io-redirection, job-scheduling, powershell-7.4

This is a mock up of part of the code I'm working on

```
$output = @()

Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
    try {    
        Write-Host "`nThis is a Write-Host message"
        Write-Verbose 'This is a verbose message.' -Verbose
        Start-Sleep 2  
        throw 'this is an error message'
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host 'Error: ' $_.Exception.Message
    }
} -ThrottleLimit 1 -StreamingHost $Host
```

I need to know if there is any way to redirect the output of the ThreadJob to a variable when using `-StreamingHost $Host` parameter. I don't want to use `Receive-Job` because that already works, I'm trying to see if it's possible to eliminate an extra step (and background task) by utilizing the `-StreamingHost` parameter of the `Start-ThreadJob` cmdlet.

Maybe it's possible to create a new host and then capture the data from there? I just need the string output of the thread job.

I don't want to modify the script block itself by redirecting the output inside of there.

I'm using PowerShell 7.5-beta

Comment: Not without a custom PSHost if hooking to the runspace.